# Styling BibLaTeX's pagination ouput

Tags: biblatex, color, citing, tcolorbox

I commonly use the pagination field when citing sources with `biblatex`, for example:

```
\cite[Ch. 5]{Source2001}
\cites[Ch. 5]{Source2001}[p. 231]{Source2002}{Source2003}
```

[image]

For more clarity, I would like to visually separate the pagination from the citation itself, somewhat like in this dirty mockup I made using [`tcolorbox`](https://ctan.org/pkg/tcolorbox):

[image]

**How can I do this?**
I'm presuming I'll need to redefine some command, but I don't even know where to begin looking in `biblatex`'s source code.

---

Code for the above mockup:

```
\newtcbox{citenote}{on line, boxsep=0.1pt, left=1pt,right=1pt,top=2pt,bottom=2pt,coltext=black!55, fontupper=\footnotesize,enlarge by=0pt, arc=2pt, colframe=white, colback=black!4}
```

```
{[}1\,\citenote{Ch. 5}{]}\\
{[}1\,\citenote{Ch. 5}, 2\,\citenote{p. 231}, 3{]}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change the formatting of the page reference by redefining the `postnote` field format.

Its default definition is

```
\DeclareFieldFormat{postnote}{\mkpageprefix[pagination][\mknormrange]{#1}}
```

[see l. 477 of biblatex.def [v3.16]](https://github.com/plk/biblatex/blob/ca032db14c25fcad84a75ce5f43ba59c39ac69f2/tex/latex/biblatex/biblatex.def#L477).

You can just add your `\citenote`.

```
\documentclass[british]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\usepackage[backend=biber, style=authoryear]{biblatex}

\newtcbox{citepostnotebox}{
  on line, boxsep=0.1pt,
  left=1pt,right=1pt,top=2pt,bottom=2pt,
  enlarge by=0pt, arc=2pt,
  fontupper=\footnotesize,
  coltext=black!55, colframe=white, colback=black!4}

\DeclareDelimFormat{postnotedelim}{\addspace}
\DeclareFieldFormat{postnote}{%
  \citepostnotebox{%
    \mkpageprefix[pagination][\mknormrange]{#1}}}

\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\begin{document}
Lorem \autocite[380]{sigfridsson}
Lorem \autocite[Ch.~1]{nussbaum}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: Lorem (Sigfridsson and Ryde 1998 p. 380) Lorem (Nussbaum 1978 Ch. 1) with "p. 380" and "Ch. 1" boxed]