# Change postnote (pages) formatting for \parencite

Tags: biblatex

First a minimal working sample is as follows.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[style=authoryear-comp]{biblatex}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}[overwrite]{\jobname.bib}
@ARTICLE{jensen1916,
    AUTHOR = {A. Jensen and B. Bonus and N. Loretan and D. Yong},
    TITLE = {Bemerkninger til dagligtalen i Kristiania},
    JOURNALTITLE = {Maal og Minne},
    YEAR = {1916},
    NUMBER = {1--2},
    PAGES = {60--89}}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}
\parencite[72]{jensen1916}

\nocite{*}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

And as you see, its output is as follows.

[image]

How to make the `\parencite` be the format: (author year + colon + page numbers), for example, (Jensen et al. 1916: 72)?

[image]

Comment: See also https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/619985/35864, https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/509637/35864. Related: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/598511/35864.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[style=authoryear-comp]{biblatex}

\DeclareDelimFormat{postnotedelim}{\addcolon\space}
\DeclareFieldFormat{postnote}{\mknormrange{#1}}

\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\begin{document}
\parencite[72]{sigfridsson}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: (Sigfridsson and Ryde 1998: 72)]